# How do I register NodaTime in ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, servicestack, nodatime, funq

I am using the latest ServiceStack and want to use NodaTime instead of the .NET DateTime classes.  The recommendations I've read show using a property based on IClock, which I've done.  Now I need to inject the IClock, but what I've tried is not working.  I tried:

```
container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<SystemClock, IClock>();
```

but I receive the exception "Constructor not found for Type'SystemClock'.

I also tried

```
container.RegisterAutoWired<Instant>();
```

which compiles, but doesn't inject IClock.

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to register `IClock` with:

```
container.Register<IClock>(c => SystemClock.Instance);
```